# Zend Framework 2 validation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
        'name' => 'amount',

        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'string_length',
                'options' => array(
                    'max' => 60,
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\StringLength::TOO_LONG => 'Title  should be less than %max% characters',
                    ),
```

How to add numeric validation for this code ?

Comment: I dont see a reason for downvote question is valid as there are few examples online Regarding ZF2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Int or Float validators: [I18n Validators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.i18n.validators.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
    'name' => 'amount',

    'validators' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'string_length',
            'options' => array(
                'max' => 60`
'messages' => array(
                    \Zend\Validator\Digits::NOT_DIGITS => 'It is not a Valid Numeric Character',
Note: Validating numbers
```

When you want to validate numbers or numeric values, be aware that this validator only validates digits. This means that any other sign like a thousand separator or a comma will not pass this validator. In this case you should use Zend_Validate_Int or Zend_Validate_Float.